# XCOPY with a little twist

Tags: windows, script

not sure if this is asked before but I need to move files from one location to another with a little twist.

I have the following script written:

```
@ECHO OFF
set source=C:\folder1\folder2
set destination=\\10.10.0.2\c$\folder1

echo COPY FILES FROM src TO dest
xcopy %source% %destination% /s /y
echo COPY DONE

echo COPY FILES FROM dest TO src
xcopy %destination% %source% /s /y
echo COPY DONE
```

- I need to make sure in the first copy only files that do not contain
  the word "BOB" at the start are transferred.
- On the second copy I need to make sure only files that contain the word "BOB" is transferred back.

The Twist:

I've never done this before but in order for this script to work the destination location should be logged into and I found the following command but I'm not sure if this can be used in the script? if yes do I simply add it to the top of the file?

```
net use X: \\Hostname\Share password /savecred /p:yes
```

Thanks.

Comment: I managed to figure out second transfer and it works fine: xcopy %destination%\BOB* %source% /s /y

Comment: I know /EXCLUDE:c:\excludelist.txt can be used to remove the files we don't want to transfer but is there anyway of making this dynamic e.g. any files that don't include BOB to begin with as we have files being added all the time and a .txt file with a list of the is not feasible.

Comment: Create the exclude list using `dir /b %source%\BOB* > c:\excludelist.txt`

Comment: Thanks David, If I do that what goes inside the exclude file then? I was trying to avoid listing every single file.

Comment: The `dir` cmd **creates** the exclude file with the appropriate entries. You need to `cd %source%` as well before running `dir` and the `xcopy`

Comment: @DavidPostill worked perfectly, thank you! do you know how I can stop folders copying? Just want to transfers files but sometimes we have archive folders with older version of the file and they get copied too.

Comment: You would need to add the archive directories to the exclude file. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I need to move files from one location to another with a little twist.

Try the following variation of your batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
set source=C:\folder1\folder2
set destination=\\10.10.0.2\c$\folder1

rem change to the source directory
cd %source%

rem create an exclude file
dir /b BOB* > c:\excludelist.txt

echo COPY FILES FROM src TO dest
rem add /exclude to xcopy
xcopy %source% %destination% /exclude:c:\excludelist.txt /s /y

rem cleanup
del c:\excludelist.txt
echo COPY DONE

echo COPY FILES FROM dest TO src
xcopy %destination% %source% /s /y
echo COPY DONE
```

Note:

```
See the lines starting with `rem` for additions/modifications to your original file.
```

---

#### how I can stop folders copying?

> Just want to transfers files but sometimes we have archive folders with older version of the file and they get copied too

You would need to add the archive directories to the exclude file.

Add an additional line something like the following **after** the first `dir` command:

```
dir /a:d /b archive* >> c:\excludelist.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.